# Installing OpenCV on linux: getting CMake Error

Tags: javascript, opencv, cmake, installation

I am trying to install OpenCV on linux to use with nodejs.

I followed the instructions in https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/da1/tutorial_js_setup.html and got the version 4.0.0 of OpenCV from the release page.

When I run the following command in my `opencv` directory :

```
python ./platforms/js/build_js.py  --emscripten_dir ~/emsdk/ build_js
```

I get the following error:

```
Re-run cmake no build system arguments
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/CMakeDetermineSystem.cmake:104 (message):
  Could not find toolchain file:
  ~/emsdk/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:131 (project)


CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 224, in <module>
    builder.config()
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 164, in config
    execute(cmd)
  File "./platforms/js/build_js.py", line 23, in execute
    raise Fail("Child returned: %s" % retcode)
__main__.Fail: Child returned: 1
```

I get the same error when I try and install OpenCV via (I have successfully installed OPenCV with these commands before, but I am not sure why now the same command is failing):

```
mkdir release
cd release
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

My cMake version is `cmake version 3.5.1`.

**EDIT**

Like it has been suggested, `apt-get install cmake gcc g++` then cmake in a new directory solved the issue. 
I still had other errors afterwards and at the end I had to downgrade my node js to v8.12.0 and install opencv via `npm install opencv` (that command gave lots of errors with the latest version of nodejs (11.2)).

Comment: it looks like if the c++/c compiler are not there... do something like `apt-get install cmake gcc g++` not sure what is your linux flavor so this command is for ubuntu. Remember to remove the CMakeCache.txt file or to do cmake in a clean directory

Comment: Does the file `~/emsdk/cmake/Modules/Platform/Emscripten.cmake` exists or not actually? If it exists, try to replace `~` with exact path to home directory. If the file misses, you probably specify wrong emscripten directory.

Comment: @api55 `apt-get install cmake gcc g++` did help, when I redid the cmake in a clean directory! thank you.